# Wordpress: Add orderby field in search form

Tags: wordpress, search

I have created a WordPress custom search form for a particular custom post type. The results are showing up in an order other than newest posts first. I would like the search results to be displayed with the newest custom posts first. Is there a hidden field that I can add to the search form, so the results will show in date order DESC?

I tried:

```
<input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="date" />
```

and

```
<input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="post_date DESC" />
```

but neither worked.

Here is my search form code:

```
<div class="event-search-form">
  <form method="get" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_attr( $action ); ?>"<?php wpex_aria_landmark( 'searchform' ); ?>>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="ai1ec_event" />
    <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="date" />
    <input type="hidden" name="order" value="DESC" />
    <label>
      <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo esc_html( $placeholder ); ?></span>
      <input type="search" class="field" name="s" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr( $placeholder ); ?>" />
  </label>
  <?php if ( defined( 'ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE' ) ) : ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="<?php echo( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE ); ?>"/>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php do_action( 'wpex_searchform_fields' ); ?>
  <button type="submit" class="searchform-submit"><span class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Submit', 'total' ); ?></span></button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I also tried adding this to my theme's functions.php file, but it didn't work either:`code`// Group Search results by post type descending date order
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'brew2015_group_by_post_type', 10, 2);
function brew2015_group_by_post_type($orderby, $query) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(!is_admin() && is_search()) {
        $orderby =  $wpdb->prefix."posts.post_type DESC, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date DESC";
 } 
    return $orderby;
}

Comment: Try setting the `form` `action` to `/` or `home_url( '/' )`. So, `<form method="get" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_attr( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"<?php wpex_aria_landmark( 'searchform' ); ?>>`